# Need help understanding computation of area and volume using Matrices and linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, area, volume

I am currently studying linear algebra from Gilbert R Strang's book. I have a few questions regarding computing area using matrices.

In the book, for a triangle with coordinates:
$(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, $(x_3, y_3)$

The area is given as 1/2*det($$
    \begin{matrix}
    x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
    x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
    x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$)

**1. Is the intuition behind adding the column of 1's just to make it into a square matrix?**

Moving onto calculating volume of a rectangle with sides of length (r,s,t).
The coordinate matrix will be:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    r & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & s & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & t \\
    r & s & 0 \\
    0 & s & t \\
    r & 0 & t \\
    r & s & t \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

**2. Going by the logic applied to compute area of triangle, will I need to add 5 columns of 1's in order to get the volume.**

**Because in the book, the author mentions that computing the determinant of the diagonal matrix A with diagonal entries r,s,t would give the volume as rst** (which is true by the L*b*h formula)

**3. But, what I fail to understand is how does a computing the determinant of a subset of three vectors give me the volume?**

Also if I use the three vectors (r,s,0) , (r, 0 ,t) and (0, s, t) to do the same, the value of the determinant is -2rst which is the incorrect volume. **Do the three vectors chosen need to be perpendicular?**

**4. Basically I am having trouble wrapping my head around how you need all three coordinates to compute the area but only 3 coordinates (vectors?) to compute the volume despite there being 8 coordinates that bound the rectangle in 3D space.**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product

Comment: In the book the author hasn't mentioned triple product for this problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Why a Column of Ones is Added**

The volume of the [parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) that is [generated by the vectors $u,v,w$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped#/media/File:Parallelepiped-v.svg) is given by
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
u_x&u_y&u_z\\
v_x&v_y&v_z\\
w_x&w_y&w_z
\end{bmatrix}\tag1
$$
The volume of the [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) whose vertices are $0,u,v,w$ is [$\frac16$ of the volume of the parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume).

[image]

Furthermore, the volume of any [pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)) is [$\frac13\times|\text{base}|\times\text{altitude}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)#Volume). By setting the $z$-coordinate of each vertex of the triangle to $1$, we have essentially set the altitude to $1$ (the dotted line in the rotating image) and the base to the triangle. Thus, the area of the triangle is
$$
3\times\text{volume}=\frac12\det\begin{bmatrix}
u_x&u_y&1\\
v_x&v_y&1\\
w_x&w_y&1
\end{bmatrix}\tag2
$$
**2. Rectangle With Given Measurements**

A rectangle with edges $r,s,t$ is a parallelepiped generated by $(r,0,0),(0,s,0),(0,0,t)$, and so its volume is
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}r&0&0\\0&s&0\\0&0&t\end{bmatrix}=rst\tag3
$$
**3. Why the Determinant of Three Vectors Gives the Volume of a Rectangle**

A rectangle is a parallelepiped generated by the three vectors used.